# Is there a way to not inherit a specific property?

Tags: kotlin

[image]

I'm trying to group my classes like images.

It is a structure in which one `header` and several `items` are gathered in one group to form a list.

If the `Header` property and `Item list` properties are placed in the `sealed class`, the subclass inherits this, so the structure becomes strange.

So, I want to make it impossible to inherit only Header property and Item list property in sealed class. Is there a way?

**GroupedItem**

```
sealed class GroupedItem(val layoutId : Int = 1) {
    val header: Header = Header() // I want to make inheritance impossible
    val itemList: List<Item> = listOf() // I want to make inheritance impossible

    data class Header(
        val id: String = "",
    ) : GroupedItem(someValue)

    data class Item(
        val id: String = "",
        val set: Int = 1,
    ) : GroupedItem(someValue)
}
```

**Grouping example**

```
for (i in 0 until headerNumber) {
    val headerText = "Header $i"
    val header = GroupedItem.Header(headerText)
    val itemList = arrayListOf<GroupedItem.Item>()
    val indexNumber = Random.nextInt(2, 5)
    for (j in 0 until indexNumber) {
        val itemText = "Item $j"
        itemList.add(GroupedItem.Item(itemText))
    }
    val groupedItem = GroupedItem(header, itemList)
    groupedItemList.add(groupedItem)
}
```

---

***ADDED***

**Main**

```
fun main() {
    val test = RoutineItem.Header()

    println(test.id)
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at RoutineItem$Header.<init>(hello.kt)
    at RoutineItem$Header.<init>(hello.kt:18)
    at RoutineItem.<init>(hello.kt:15)
    at RoutineItem.<init>(hello.kt)
    at RoutineItem$Header.<init>(hello.kt:22)
    at RoutineItem$Header.<init>(hello.kt:18)
    at RoutineItem.<init>(hello.kt:15)
    at RoutineItem.<init>(hello.kt)
``
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the header, and itemList as private. It sounds like this is what you are looking for

Comment: Of course I tried, but the result is the same.

Comment: to me it just sounds like you want `Header` and `Item` to belong to different hierarchies. Why do they both extend `GroupedItem` if you want the group to just be a container of 1 Header + N items?

Comment: @user2340612 
I am trying to use this in `android studio`. After setting the `layoutId` property in `GroupedItem`, I tried to inherit from `Header` and `Item` respectively. Is this the wrong way?

Comment: what is `layoutId` identifying? Is it equivalent to the group ID (e.g. "group1", "group2" and so on) in your example? @cactustictacs's answer explains what I meant with my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're defining it, a `Header` **is** a `GroupedItem`, and every `GroupedItem` has a `Header`, which is incorrect, right? It seems like you want one of these:

**`GroupedItem` represents a category of items that go in your groups, i.e. `Header`s and `ItemList`s:**

You can use an interface, but a sealed class is fine for this (and gives you the `GroupedItem.Thing` namespacing). Since `GroupedItem` is a general category, it shouldn't contain a `Header` or anything else, just like a `Vehicle` shouldn't have a `Car` property

---

**`GroupedItem` represents a structure that contains a `Header` and an `ItemList` (possibly optional):**

In this case, `Header` isn't a `GroupedItem` at all (same as a `Wheel` isn't a `Car`) and shouldn't inherit from it - it has no relation to that class. `GroupedItem` just happens to include a `Header` as a property.

If you want the `GroupedItem.Thing` naming scheme to keep things organised, you can just make `Header` a class within `GroupedItem` (not an `inner` class though):

```
class GroupedItem(
    val header: Header = Header(),
    val itemList: List<Item> = listOf()
){

    data class Header(
        val id: String = "",
    )

    data class Item(
        val id: String = "",
        val set: Int = 1,
    )
}
```

you'll have to sort out where `layoutId` is coming from though.

---

honestly though, I think you probably want both of these things:

- `GroupedItem` to represent things that go in groups
- `Group` for an actual concrete group of those things

```
class Group(
    val header: Header = Header()
    val itemList: List<Item> = listOf()
)

sealed class GroupedItem(val layoutId : Int = 1) {
    data class Header(
        val id: String = "",
    ) : GroupedItem(someValue)

    data class Item(
        val id: String = "",
        val set: Int = 1,
    ) : GroupedItem(someValue)
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm sorry, but let me ask you a few questions. `Q1`. I don't understand what you're saying "`Since GroupedItem is a general category, it shouldn't contain a Header or anything else, just like a Vehicle shouldn't have a Car property`". `Q2`. Isn't it really desirable to have a class in the `GroupedItem` class like the second part? `Q3`. In the code of the last part, it's not exactly `Header`, but `RoutineItem.Header`, right? Same goes for Item.

Comment: Well what **is** a ``GroupedItem``? Is it a *type* of thing, a property that you can apply to something to say it's an item that goes in a group?  Or is it an actual object that acts as a group, and contains instances of those items? It can't be both, otherwise a ``Header`` **is** a ``GroupedItem``, which **contains** a ``Header``, which **is** a ``GroupedItem``... etc. Sticking non-``inner`` classes inside other classes is just an organisation/naming convenience thing, and I don't know what ``RoutineItem`` is - you've used both in your question. Just name them whatever makes sense!